# Add text to input field instead of replacing it with ListView + jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, listview, mobile, filter

What I am trying to accomplish:

Clicking a button adds a word to filter the jQuery Mobile ListView.

HTML:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a" data-divider-theme="c">
                <li data-role="list-divider" data-inset="true">
                    <div data-role="controlgroup"  data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true" id="filterButton">
                        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Iedereen</a>
                        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true">LinkedIn</a>
                        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Facebook</a>
                        <a data-role="button" style="width: 4px;"></a>
                        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" class="filterAdd">Design</a>
                        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Development</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="d" data-filter-placeholder="Search Connections...">
                <li data-theme="b"><a href="index.html">
                    <img src="http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1353509401/DSC_3465_bigger.jpg" class="ui-li-thumb zapp-corner zapp-margin-5 zapp-inner-shadow" />
                    <h3>Stephen Weber</h3>
                    <p><strong>You've been invited to a meeting at Filament Group in Boston, MA</strong></p>
                    <p>Hey Stephen, if you're available at 10am tomorrow, we've got a meeting with the jQuery team.</p>
                    <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>LinkedIn</strong></p>
                </a></li>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#filterButton").delegate("a", "click", function () {
                        $("div.ui-input-search").find("input").val($(this).text());
                        $("div.ui-input-search").find("input").keyup();
                    });
});
```

At this moment it replaces the whole value inside the input field instead of adding it to the existing value.

http://jsfiddle.net/J4HZp/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#filterButton").delegate("a", "click", function () {
     var txt = $(this).text();
     $("div.ui-input-search").find("input").val(function(i, currentValue) {
        return currentValue + txt;
     }).trigger('keyup');
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what he asked for, but I would `.trigger('keyup')`. I don't really think in this scenario it's too much of an issue, but most of the time people simply want to trigger any functions attached to the event handler, and not to trigger the event it's self.

Comment: This did the job! I used .trigger('keyup') because otherwise I got the same result twice (it repeated the word). http://jsfiddle.net/J4HZp/8/